# Difference between JavaScript Function

Tags: javascript, jsp

I have some doubt in my mind that if a jsp page `onclick()` calls a JavaScript method.

I have two scenarios

1. `onclick="return validatePage();"`
2. `onclick="validatePage();"`

What is the difference between these two types calling of JavaScript methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you return false from the javascript function ,**onclick = "return validatePage();"** wont submit the form values.

where as, in the case of **onclick = "validatePage();"** will submit the form values even if you return false from the Javascript function.

Comment: Well explained. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

On the first, by returning the return value of the function, you will cancel the default action for the event when the function returns `false`. Similar to calling [`event.preventDefault()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/event.preventDefault). It is notably used when checking for forms validity, where returning `false` will cancel the form submission.

ps. In the case of form validation, instead of binding the validation function a button's `onclick`, you should attach it to the form's `onsubmit` event. This way if the user triggers the submit through pressing Enter on an input, the form will still be checked before submitting.

Comment: Returning false doesn't "cancel the event", it just stops the default action for that element. The event will still propagate if it's an event that propagates (such as click).

Comment: @RobG Yes you're right. My initially bad assumption was based on jQuery handlers which by returning false do `preventDefault` and `stopPropagation`. I'll update the answer to reword the "cancel" statement.

Answer (score 1):

For an onclick event those two scenarios are essentially equivalent. The reason you would use "return" is more closely related to an onsubmit event of a form instead of onclick. When you use it with onsubmit, if the function returns false it will prevent the form from being submitted.

Answer (score 0):

Number 1 will return the value, returned by the `validatePage();` function. This can be used to interrupt key presses, for example (returning `false` on the `onkeyup` of a input field), or to use a anchor (`<a href="....` ) as a JavaScript button.
Number 2 will simply execute the function.